# Robot Framework wxPython Not Found on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, robotframework

I have copied Python folder from my colleague's window machine (where robot framework is running successfully), but whenever i am trying to open ride.py, i am always getting:

```
wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpytho n/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

So, i have same python version, same robot framework version etc as my colleague. What else should i check now.

Comment: The error says it all - you need to install wxPython just download and reinstall at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/ - make sure you select the correct version

Comment: As already mentioned, same wxPython works at my colleagues machine. So, that cant be the issue.

Comment: But something has gone wrong somewhere in transfer. Have you tried to reinstall it? Or perhaps it's pointing to a path which works for your colleagues machine but not your own?

Comment: which path should i check?

Comment: if python is installed in `C directory` then you should check in the path `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wxPython`  in this path`wx-2.8-msw-unicode` is the name of wxpython version you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, when i uninstalled wxpython and ride both and then reinstalled wxpython first and then ride.